# Choose buttons in the template

Tags: html

I am building a BlogApp and I am working in a Image Cropping Feature AND i am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

There's a Image Cropping Feature in Create BlogPost page. AND when user fill all the details then user selects a image from Directory and crop it and THEN **The Problem Is**, There are two buttons in Image Cropping Section `Back` and `Crop and Upload` button. AND When user clicks on Back then it return to the `Create Blog` page without selected the image( which is good ) *BUT* when it click on `Crop and Upload` then blog is saving without return to `Create Blog` page and I want a button of `Select this Image` , So when user clicks on button then it will return in `Create Post Section` with the selected image.

BUT i don't know how can i do it.

**What have i tried**

- I have tried `<input type="submit" value="okay" />` BUT it didn't work for me.
- I have also tried ` tag, BUT it also didn't work for me.

create_post.html

```
{% block javascript %}


  <script>
      $(function () {

          
          $("#id_file").change(function () {
              if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                      $("#image").attr("src", e.target.result);
                      $("#modalCrop").modal("show");
                  }
                  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
              }
          });

         
          var $image = $("#image");
          var cropBoxData;
          var canvasData;
          $("#modalCrop").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
              $image.cropper({
                  viewMode: 1,
                  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                  minCropBoxWidth: 200,
                  minCropBoxHeight: 200,
                  ready: function () {
                      $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
                      $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
                  }
              });
          }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
              cropBoxData = $image.cropper("getCropBoxData");
              canvasData = $image.cropper("getCanvasData");
              $image.cropper("destroy");
          });

          $(".js-zoom-in").click(function () {
              $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
          });

          $(".js-zoom-out").click(function () {
              $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
          });

         
          $(".js-crop-and-upload").click(function () {
              var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
              $("#id_x").val(cropData["x"]);
              $("#id_y").val(cropData["y"]);
              $("#id_height").val(cropData["height"]);
              $("#id_width").val(cropData["width"]);
              $("#formUpload").submit();
          });

      });
  </script>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block content %}

  <div class="container">
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
      {% csrf_token %}

   {{ form }}


  <div id="uploadedFile"></div>

  <br>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

    $(function() {
      $( ".date_added" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1900:2012",
        // You can put more options here.

      });
    });
    </script>


  </form>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modalCrop">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Crop the photo</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <img src="" id="image" style="max-width: 100%;">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <div class="btn-group pull-left" role="group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-in">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-out">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span>
                      </button>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Go Back</button>
   
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-crop-and-upload">Crop and upload</button>



              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time to gather plugins and css to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

If I understand, you want a button on the modal, that will allow the user to return to the post before uploading?

I had to add missing fields like id_x etc and I updated the jQuery to a recent version

The libraries must be loaded in the order shown

```js
const crop = () => {
  var $image = $("#image");
  var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
  $("#id_x").val(cropData["x"]);
  $("#id_y").val(cropData["y"]);
  $("#id_height").val(cropData["height"]);
  $("#id_width").val(cropData["width"]);
}

$(function() {

  /* SCRIPT TO OPEN THE MODAL WITH THE PREVIEW */
  $("#id_file").change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $("#image").attr("src", e.target.result);
        $("#modalCrop").modal("show");
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });

  /* SCRIPTS TO HANDLE THE CROPPER BOX */
  var $image = $("#image");
  var cropBoxData;
  var canvasData;
  $("#modalCrop").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $image.cropper({
      viewMode: 1,
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
      minCropBoxWidth: 200,
      minCropBoxHeight: 200,
      ready: function() {
        $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
        $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
      }
    });
  }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    cropBoxData = $image.cropper("getCropBoxData");
    canvasData = $image.cropper("getCanvasData");
    $image.cropper("destroy");
  });

  $(".js-zoom-in").click(function() {
    $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
  });

  $(".js-zoom-out").click(function() {
    $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
  });


  /* SCRIPT TO COLLECT THE DATA AND POST TO THE SERVER */
  $(".js-crop-and-upload").click(function() {
    crop()
    $("#formUpload").submit();
  });
  $(".js-crop-only").click(function() {
    crop()
    $("#modalCrop").modal("hide");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/4.1.0/cropper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/4.1.0/cropper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">


<div class="container">
  <!-- FORM TO UPLOAD THE IMAGES -->
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
    Image: <input type="file" id="id_file" />
    <div id="uploadedFile"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_x" />
    <input type="hidden" id="id_y" />
    <input type="hidden" id="id_height" />
    <input type="hidden" id="id_width" />
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="button button4">Save Changes</button>



  </form>
</div>

<!-- MODAL TO CROP THE IMAGE -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCrop">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Crop the photo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" id="image" style="max-width: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-group pull-left" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-in">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-out">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Go Back</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-crop-and-upload">Crop and upload</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-crop-only">Select this image</button>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```